# "Janus face" or "Janus faces"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

In both cases, a google search seems to gives titles of journal articles. It is very strange for some journals to publish titles with wrong spelling. Yet, I cannot determine which is standard language (dictionaries only contain the word "Janus-faced").

The title is to be used in the following context:

> The Janus face(s) of sociological research in XXX

Comment: Your meaning isn't clear.  Are you trying to determine if a two faced Janus should be pluralized when referring to it's face(s)? Or are you simply trying to call some sociological research two faced in a fancy way?

Comment: I wanted to use the metaphor of "Janus face(s)" to express (1) that something has two faces/sides (2) the two faces/aspects are not separable, (3) one face/side is deceitful. These connotations seems to apply well to the topic I want to discuss.

My confusion is the following: the mythical figure is singular, its faces are plural, yet, the two faces are not separable (so singular, after all?). I don't know what the correct use is. Especially when connected with the other part of the sentence, i.e. "The Janus face(s) of sociological research in XXX"

Comment: (p.s. I am not a native speaker, so I don't have good intuition)

Comment: If you're not a native speaker consider using ell.stackexchange.com.  Though I must say, I couldn't tell from your post.

Comment: Janus is singular, but the faces are obviously plural. I wouldn't hesitate to use "the Janus faces".

Comment: Although I recognise the adjective *Janus-faced*, I'm not aware of the noun *Janus face/s* being a common idiom in English, so neither is natural. I'd recommend you just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that goes either way.  If I tell you I saw Janus faces you can't be sure if that means I saw at least 2 or 4 singular faces.  That depends on if I think of a Janus face as one of the two faces on a Janus or both faces on a Janus.

More important than any of that is making your meaning clear.

> 1) The two Janus face**s** of sociological research in XXX are A and B.
>
> 2) The Janus face of sociological research in XXX is A and B.

If that was the structure you were going for I'd pick 1) just because it saves the reader from having to think about it so hard.

Comment: Since *two* modifies *face[s]*, *faces* should be left in the plural if *two* is inserted; *face[s]* and *are* should also agree. You might have a case with the OP's original phrase, though.

Comment: @Lawrence OK I'll remove the two.  I'd still argue that 1) is clearer.

Comment: If the second is just for illustration, you could leave it in its original form and simply point out that it is ungrammatical or awkward. The current form of the second has the same issues as the phrase "the *pair* is A and B". It sounds better if you replace *is* with *admits both* or *spans*, etc.